# PNG picture having big transparent sides that I don't need.HTML

Tags: html, css, image, png

I'm using an image with the  tags in HTML and changing its width in CSS. Everything is good except the big transparent sides the picture has, it's not padding or anything else, I think these are just the sides that the image has. I tried removing the padding, but it doesn't work, even making the padding a negative value doesn't make it any better. It's the site's logo so it would look quite awfully with the logo in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably white space from the image itself, you need to crop it in some image editing software like PhotoShop (try this free online version https://www.photopea.com/) or some free alternative like GIMP. Also you will maybe be able to make those types of change in stock image editing software on your machine.